# Get Cookie of another Domain Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, cookies

can someone take a look on my snippet and correct me if he know whats i made false. Thank you in advance.

I need to get cookies from a url in javascript.. 
My approach was to open the url in a new tab and set the cookies to the local storage but theres nothing in the storage

btw this is about a chrome extension

```
var w = window.open('urlWithCookies');
w.focus();

localStorage.setItem('allCookies', document.cookie);

w.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

Due to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), you cannot read or set cookies, localStorage items and the like for other domains. If it were possible in a certain webbrowser, that would be a gaping security hole and quickly fixed.

Instead, arrange another way to communicate with the website. For instance, the website may use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to give you access to some data, or you may contact a web *server* of yours who then communicates with the website.